# Adding the user who posted a topic in a database

Tags: php, database, fetch

I have a table `TOPICS` in my database, which doesn't state which user opened it. In my `MESSAGES` table, however, there is a `USER` column which shows which user opened it. My question is: how can I give my `TOPICS` table a column with users and fetch this information?

Now, I have the last message of a user in each profile, but as said, I can't **show a link to the topic and the topicname**, because there is no such column in `TOPICS`. How can I make this possible?

I used this to fetch the last message of a user, which worked:

```
$lastpost = execute_scalar("SELECT message FROM messages where messages.user='$who' Order by date desc");
```

Now I need to do the same for the topic.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I understand your needs but correct me if I'm wrong...

You can..

1 - add column in user table 'LastTopicId'

2- make new table 'UserOpenTopic' with foreign key to User and Topic, with date... So you can do query

`$lastpost = query("SELECT topic.TopicName FROM UserOpenTopic INNER JOIN topic ON topic.ID = UserOpenTopic.TopicID where UserOpenTopic.userID='$who' Order by date desc");`

And you should have last topic ( and whole history ) for every user on topic...

Comment: The problem is that if I add a column user, it does not show the user. It shows a IP-adres, a ID etc. but no user or whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that a message is always related to a topic, so you should add a n:1 relation from *messages* to *topics*. Dependent on the type of fields and naming conventions in your table schema it should be something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `messages` ADD `topicId` INT NOT NULL;
```

In this case the relation is build actually as a *foreign key* to Id which of course must exist in your table *topics*. When storing messages, you have to take care of also storing this related topicID (or the corresponding primary key of the table *topics*). When fetching messages you have to join it:

```
SELECT message,user FROM messages,topics WHERE messages.topicId = topics.Id AND messages.user='$who' ORDER BY messages.date DESC
```

Please check the mysql documentation (CREATE, ALTER and SELECT syntax) for more detailed examples. When using an ORM please check examples for building and handling *hasMany* relations.

Comment: I added a column as you suggested in your first code, but then it does not show the user. I tried to add a user column in to the topics column, but it just said zero everywhere.